# upload image from react native app to symfony backend via axios

Tags: react-native, symfony, post, axios, multipartform-data

I want to upload an image from react native app to backend in symfony via axios.

here is the code of the front end :

```
    const [pickedImage, setPickedImage] = useState("");
    const submitPhoto = async () => {
    try {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
    setPickedImage(result);
          
    let formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("uploaded_image", {
            uri:
              Platform.OS === "android"
                ? pickedImage.uri
                : pickedImage.uri.replace("file://", ""),
            name: "tata.jpeg",
            type: "image/jpeg",
          });
          const response = await axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://192.168.1.3:8000/upload",
            data: formData,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      };
```

here is the code of the backend in Symfony :

```
public function postImage(Request $request)
{
//... some code
$content = $request->files->get("uploaded_image");
// ... handle the image in content
}
```

As I can see, $content is NULL. And to confirm it, I attached a screenshot of the profiler of symfony.

[image]

I tried to add "Content-type": "multipart/form-data" in the axios call, but i get : "Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data"

Does anyone know how I can properly upload the image from react native to Symfony ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1 :
When using POSTMAN, the backend works as you can see in the two following images :

POSTMAN REQUEST :
[image]

PROFILER SYMFONY :
[image]

Comment: Maybe try to set `Content-Type: undefined`

Comment: It does not work ! I see in the symfony profiler that content-type is set to "application/json" even thought i put Content-Type: undefined in the front end
Thanks for the proposition

Comment: are you using react-native with managed workflow(Expo)?

Comment: Yes I am using it indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said, when i use Axios with the right header (multipart/form-data), I get a message error :

> Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data

.

I tried to use fetch, and it works now ! I dont know why :

```
let response = await fetch(
        "http://192.168.1.3:8000/upload",
         {
           method: "post",
           body: formData,
           headers : {
             'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data;'
           }
         }
      )
```

It is weird, but I dont know why it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you get a base64 in your back-end side, then you have to convert it with something like :

```
    $data = base64_decode($content);
    file_put_contents($filePath, $data);
```

Comment: your answer is not relevant as I dont use coding / decoding in base64